# Tindercard swipe with calender Flutter

Tags: flutter, calendar, swipe

[image]

Is there any library available for Tinder card swipe with calendar view. While swipe it should open next month calendar.  We have library tinder swipe and calendar separately  and able merge it together but  not able open next month with swipe. Is there any way we can do this or we need to create own view calendar?

```
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return 
  Expanded(
    child: Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    backCard(),
    middleCard(),
    frontCard(),

    // Prevent swiping if the cards are animating
    _controller.status != AnimationStatus.forward
        ? SizedBox.expand(
            child: GestureDetector(
            // While dragging the first card
            onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
              // Add what the user swiped in the last frame to the alignment of the card
              setState(() {
                // 20 is the "speed" at which moves the card
                frontCardAlign = Alignment(
                    frontCardAlign.x +
                        20 *
                            details.delta.dx /
                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    frontCardAlign.y +
                        40 *
                            details.delta.dy /
                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);

                frontCardRot = frontCardAlign.x; // * rotation speed;
              });
            },
            // When releasing the first card
            onPanEnd: (_) {
              // If the front card was swiped far enough to count as swiped
              if (frontCardAlign.x > 3.0 || frontCardAlign.x < -3.0) {
                animateCards();
              } else {
                // Return to the initial rotation and alignment
                setState(() {
                  frontCardAlign = defaultFrontCardAlign;
                  frontCardRot = 0.0;
                });
              }
            },
          ))
        : Container(),
  ],
));
    }


  class ProfileCardAlignment extends StatelessWidget {
      final int cardNum;
       ProfileCardAlignment(this.cardNum);
       String _selectedDate;
     String _dateCount;
       String _range;
       String _rangeCount;

     @override
    void initState() {
     _selectedDate = '';
        _dateCount = '';
        _range = '';
      _rangeCount = '';

     }
   @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Card(
      child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
    /*  SizedBox.expand(
        child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          child: Image.asset('res/portrait.jpeg', fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox.expand(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.black54],
                  begin: Alignment.center,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter)),
        ),
                 ),*/
           Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        child:
        Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                /*Text('Card number $cardNum',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0)),
                Text('A short description.',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),*/
                Container(
                  height: 400,
                  child:  SfDateRangePicker(
                    headerStyle: DateRangePickerHeaderStyle(textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    onSelectionChanged: _onSelectionChanged,
                    selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
                    rangeSelectionColor: Colors.blue,

                    rangeTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    initialSelectedRange: PickerDateRange(
                        DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 2)),
                        DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 2))),

                  ),
                )
                    ],
                     )),
                )
               ],
              ),
              );
        }
        /// The method for [DateRangePickerSelectionChanged] callback, which will be
      /// called whenever a selection changed on the date picker widget.
        void _onSelectionChanged(DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args) {
      /// The argument value will return the changed date as [DateTime] when the
        /// widget [SfDateRangeSelectionMode] set as single.
       ///
    /// The argument value will return the changed dates as [List<DateTime>]
     /// when the widget [SfDateRangeSelectionMode] set as multiple.
       ///
    /// The argument value will return the changed range as [PickerDateRange]
     /// when the widget [SfDateRangeSelectionMode] set as range.
      ///
       /// The argument value will return the changed ranges as
      /// [List<PickerDateRange] when the widget [SfDateRangeSelectionMode] set as
       /// multi range.
       /* setState(() {
        if (args.value is PickerDateRange) {
            _range =
             DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(args.value.startDate).toString() +
            ' - ' +
            DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy')
                .format(args.value.endDate ?? args.value.startDate)
                .toString();
  } else if (args.value is DateTime) {
    _selectedDate = args.value;
  } else if (args.value is List<DateTime>) {
    _dateCount = args.value.length.toString();
  } else {
    _rangeCount = args.value.length.toString();
  }
});*/
 }
  }
```